# Video conferencing service which allows muting of individuals

Tags: video, voip

I am looking for a video conferencing service (like Skype or Cisco) with a very specific feature, which I haven't been able to find.

Consider a call with three people -- A, B, and C.  Normally, everyone can hear everyone else.  I want A to be able to mute B.  So A will not hear B, but will still hear C.  Importantly, C will also still be able to hear B -- so we can't accomplish this by having B mute his mic entirely.  I need each participant to be able to selectively mute the feeds from the other participants.

Thanks a lot for your help!